# Search Results not appearing in Coveo Search

Tags: sitecore-api, coveo

I have implemented Coveo search in my application. Its working fine on Prod but stopped working on local. The search results are not appearing in local

When I tried to figure out what is the issue , I did not get any error except in License details under control panel(Attached).Kindly suggest me how to fix this.

[image]

Comment: What is the output of your diagnostics page? Are you sure you have the proper version of Coveo for your instance of Sitecore?

Comment: Everything looks fine on Diagnostic page. There is no error overthere.

Comment: The Coveo version is 4.0 and Sitecore Version is 8.2

Comment: Is your search working? Is your rebuild working? Please take a look on your log file and paste here the entire exception stack trace.

Comment: No Search is not working. Below is stack trace.   '[InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
   Coveo.Framework.Serialization.AbstractCloudObject.GetProperty(IDictionary`2 p_Source, String p_Key, T p_DefaultValue, Boolean p_CreateIfMissing) +507
   Coveo.Framework.Serialization.AbstractCloudObject.GetProperty(String p_Key, T p_DefaultValue) +162
   Coveo.SearchProvider.Applications.Shell.Controls.LicenseInformation.SetExternalDocumentsLimitControls() +63
   Coveo.SearchProvider.Applications.Shell.Controls.LicenseInformation.UpdateFeaturesControls()'

Comment: could you please make sure you have proper Coveo license on your local?

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat can you please guide me how to update license on my local?

Comment: you should have a "coveolicense.xml" file under the data folder, same location of your Sitecore license file.

Comment: ok, I'll see and let you know. Thank you very much for quick response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue so just want to post answer if it could help anyone in future.
1-I logged in as admin.
2- Published items(Many a time Coveo throws strange error on making any code change so just republish some item and error will be gone).
3- Rebuilt index and error gone.